# fetching id from a different table for review

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm creating a social media that allows a user to review a place that he/she visited. I already passed the ratings, content and also the user id of whom reviewed the place but I seem to be having trouble passing the id for the place. Here's my controller for posting the review:

```
class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function postReview(Request $request)
        {

            $rating     = $request['rating'];
            $content    = $request['content'];

            $review     = new Review();
            $review     ->rating=$rating;
            $review     ->content=$content;

            $request->user()->reviews()->save($review);

            return redirect()->back();
        }
}
```

And here is my model for the review:

```
class Review extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'place_reviews';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Keleus\Eloquent\Place\Place');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Keleus\Eloquent\User\User');
    }

    public function scopeOfPlace($query, $placeId)
    {
        return $query->where('place_id', $placeId)->whereNotNull('place_id');
    }
}
```

Note that the input for reviews are only rating and content, user id and place id are fetched.

Comment: How will you know what place it is if you're not sending it through the form? Just add the place id to the form and get it, like you do with rating and content.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but I seem to be having trouble passing the id for the place'? It looks like you are not passing the place_id while creating a new review

Comment: @Saravanan Sampathkumar i can't get it to query to the database. Thats because i haven't added the code yet. I passed the user id but not for the place_id.